# Why do I get this syntax error?

Tags: mysql

Here's the create statement pulled out of the database itself for a trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`walkdot_logan`@`67.53.251.66` TRIGGER `wd_artists_bi_trg` BEFORE INSERT ON `wd_artists` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.modified_on is null THEN

        INSERT INTO wd_modified_records
        (modified_date, table_name, record_identifiers)
        SELECT SYSDATE(), 'artists', CONCAT('code:', NEW.code, ';');

        SET NEW.modified_on = SYSDATE();

    END IF;
END;
```

Both HeidiSQL and MySQL Workbench are complaining about syntax errors; saying that the semi-colon is missing from the `SELECT` statement line. MySQL Workbench is even underscoring the closing parenthesis to tell me I'm missing the semi-colon.

EDIT: I should point out that I've tried several insert types, and even simple select statements and the semi-colon error persists. Also, I was able to make this trigger using the trigger creator form in HeidiSQL without incident.

Comment: Have you tried with `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (SYSDATE(), 'artists', CONCAT('code:', NEW.code, ';') );`

Comment: @ypercube - Yes. I've also tried doing something simple like a `select * from table;`. It's always complaining about that missing semi-colon. What's weirder is that if I put a second semi-colon there it complains saying that it's not valid, while still showing the original error. It's like it knows it's there, but not 100%

Comment: Oh, didn't notice, you need to use `DELIMITER`. See the [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)